# Create RSS Feed JSF 2.0?

Tags: xml, model-view-controller, jsf-2, rss

i'm trying to provide an RSS feed on a site built using JSF 2.0. Before i start to code it my self, i thought i'd ask you guys if there is a standard way to do this? Googling around for a bit didn't bring up any results, however i also use CakePHP once in a while and there you can just use different views on the same model (xhtml, xml, csv whatever) which makes total sense since this is what using a MVC pattern is all about. Is there any standard layout, component or something like that i can just use? Thank you guys in advance, every hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not hugely familiar with JSF - however I have recently implemented a number of RSS feeds very quickly using Spring 3 (which internally uses the very useful ROME library).

I made particular use of Spring 3's org.springframework.web.servlet.view.feedAbstractRssFeedView which you can extend to easily allow conversion your domain objects into an RSS view with minimal effort.

The great thing is Spring has other abstract views (such as Atom, or JSON) for easy conversion of your data into other formats for RESTful consumption.

HTH.

Comment: Thank you so much, i was so focused on JSF that i totally forgot about Spring. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mashups4JSF](https://code.google.com/p/mashups4jsf/)

**Mashups4JSF** is an open source project that aims at integrating Mashup services with both Java and JSF world. JSF developers will be able to construct rich and customized mashups by using simple tags. Mashups4JSF target is to have an integrated set of Mashup tags and APIs. Mashups4JSF allows exporting the Java Enterprise Application data as Mashup feeds by annotating the application domain classes with @Feed annotation.

**Mashups4JSF 1.0.0 provides the following features**

```
Creating RSS Mashup feed sources in JSF applications using @Feed annotations. 

Creating ATOM Mashup feed sources in JSF applications using @Feed annotations. 

Reading RSS, Atom and JSON feed formats inside JSF application by using rssFeedReader, atomFeedReader, and jsonFeedReader components.

Creating Rich Google Maps with all of map details (Markers, Notes, Graphics, ...etc) declaratively using GMaps4JSF.

Getting yahoo weather information using yahooWeather component.

Performing public search in YouTube Videos using youTubeVideoList component.

Performing public search in Google using googleSearchList component.

Performing public search in Twitter using twitterSearchList component.

Performing public search in Digg using diggSearchList component.

Pretty Integration with Google Location Services.
```